# jQuery fadeOut and fadeIn and removeClass

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a transition with `jQuery` using the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` but not when I'm wrong because I'm new at this and would like a little help!

by clicking on the `"btn-login"` to hide the main `div` but action must continue to show the other `div` is actually not passing because only makes effect `fadeout` but does not remove the class `"hidden"` to him add and no does `fadeIn`

here the example:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aruu1280/)

here my script:

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-login").click(function() {

      $("#inicio_sesion").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $("recuperar_clave").removeClass("hidden").fadeIn(3000);
      });

    }); 
  });
```

Comment: Your second paragraph makes little to no sense.

Comment: Change `$("recuperar_clave")` to `$("#recuperar_clave")`. You are missing the `#`.

Comment: Thanks John it works now sry i'm block dont see it.

j08691 sry my english sucks :( i'm used google translate

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

thanks to [john-s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/859640/john-s)

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".btn-recuperar").click(function() {

      $("#inicio_sesion").fadeOut(500, function(){
          $("#recuperar_clave").fadeIn(500).removeClass("hidden");
      });

    }); 

    $(".btn-login-back").click(function() {

      $("#recuperar_clave").fadeOut(500, function(){
          $("#inicio_sesion").fadeIn(500);
      });

    }); 

  });


</script>
```